# Internet Explorer Event ID List

Tags: internet-explorer

Can anyone tell me how to get list of Event ID's regarding error available in Internet Explorer.

We are to schedule a task for these type of Event's?

Comment: Please share me if anyone knows, its urgent and important!!!

Comment: Please clarify your question.  What sort of IDs are you looking for?  Are you looking for a list of the events that IE supports?  Which version of IE?  Are you looking for command IDs associated with a given function?  Are you looking for constants that define map to COM DISPIDs?  In general, official documentation for IE can be found at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772401(v=vs.85).aspx.